# Make a child take parent overflow width

Tags: html, css

I have a number of child items inside an explicit width parent e.g.

```js
document.querySelector('.parent').scrollTo(100,0)
```

```css
.parent {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 200px;
}
.child {
  font-size: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>asdf asdf adsf asdf</div>
  <div class='child'>asdf</div>
  <div class='child'>asdf</div>
  <div class='child'>asdf</div>
  <div class='child'>asdf</div>
  <div class='child'>asdf</div>
</div>
```

**I want the `child` items background to cover the complete child.** However it doesn't extend beyond the initial visible area. You can see what I mean in the image below where I've scrolled the parent horizontally:

[image]

Comment: Did you try removing the `width: 200px`?

Comment: An explicit width on the parent is required in the design I am working on 

Comment: why inline-block doens't work for you? it seems to be the solution for me

Comment: @TemaniAfif The requirement is 'child take parent overflow width'. Reason is the children might have different contents, but the background fill for each child should be the same. I've updated the example to show children with different sizes 

Answer (score 1):

try to add `display: inline-block;` on .child element

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
  .parent {
      overflow: auto;
      width: 200px;
      background-color: blue;
    }
```

check:https://jsfiddle.net/sugandhnikhil/pLbfatgc/

Comment: Doesn’t answer “make child take parent overflow width”. In my real design the background on item will only happen on hover 

Comment: on hover you want it to take the widht of the parent??

Comment: On hover I want to change the background of the item. If the width of the item doesn't match the width of the parent, the background gets cut off 

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is going to be possible with CSS alone.  A background will take up 100% of an element's width, which in this case is 200px, not the scroll width.

Here's a bit of a hack that will get the job done with javascript.  You can get the scrollWidth of the parent and then set that to be the width of each child.  The forces each child to have the width of the longest child.

This isn't a responsive solution, however.  If you resize the text or parent for different screen sizes, you will need to recalculate the width of the children.

```js
document.querySelector('.parent').scrollTo(100,0);
var scrollWidth = document.querySelector('.parent').scrollWidth;
var children = document.querySelectorAll('.parent .child');
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    children[i].style.width = scrollWidth + "px";
}
```

```css
.parent {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 200px;
}
.child {
  font-size: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>asdf asdf adsf asdf</div>
  <div class='child'>asdf</div>
  <div class='child'>asdf</div>
  <div class='child'>asdf</div>
  <div class='child'>asdf</div>
  <div class='child'>asdf</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hack it by using `box-shadow`

```js
document.querySelector('.parent').scrollTo(100,0)
```

```css
.parent {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 200px;
}
.child {
  font-size: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  box-shadow: 200px 0 0 blue;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>asdf asdf adsf asdf</div>
  <div class='child'>asdf</div>
  <div class='child'>asdf</div>
  <div class='child'>asdf</div>
  <div class='child'>asdf</div>
  <div class='child'>asdf</div>
</div>
```